# Ubuntu 13.10 user management

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I want to create a user, say 'leon', I can create leon as a user with the 'adduser leon' command, I can give leon admin privleges by adding him to the root group with visudo.

How do I then allow leon to login in directly with his password to the server from ssh shell terminal.

I have another user set up with RSA key authentification, but would like leon to login with just password and receive the the root priveliges from the visudo append.

Comment: did you set the password for the new user 'leon' by running `passwd leon`? If so you should be able to connect already like Matty said. I would also suggest not giving a user root privileges

Answer (score 1):

The user should already be able to.

ssh -l john_smith example.com or ssh john_smith@example.com

Just as an FYI, I find it not a good idea to allow an account with root privileges to be able to log into a system remotely.  It would be safer to log in as a normal account and then use  su/sudo.

Comment: What group would you suggest I add 'Leon' to if I wanted use his password rather than an RSA key when I logon to the server. Root,Admin or Sudo

Comment: just add him to a normal group and edit the sudoers file with the necessary commands.  The only other thought would be to put Leon in a group that is setup automatically for remote access, the particulars are up to you and your environment.